# Can I change the colour of the Submit button?

Tags: cognito-forms

Can I change the colour of the submit button?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

You can change the color of the submit button. On the Publish page you can click "Form Styles" on the left side of the page. You will then be shown different styling options, one of which is Button & Link color.

[image]

Another option would be to use CSS if your form is embedded on your website. This can be done by using the following basic CSS, the color will need to be changed to the color of your choice.

.cognito #c-forms-form button {background-color:#ffffff;}